# The ring of convergent power series over $\mathbb C$ isn't noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

How can one prove that the ring of **convergent everywhere** power series in $\mathbb C[[z]]$ isn't Noetherian?

Comment: Why do you think this isn't true? It seems to be indicated as true in Zariski-Samuel Vol. II, end of page 147 to the beginning of page 148.

Comment: If I'm correct, he doesn't need series to be convergent.

Comment: He does a proof with the WPT that he prefaces by saying "which carries over almost verbatim to the convergent power series case".

Comment: May be he meant that it's true for the case of series with the nonzero radius of convergence. I found this task in the book, but this book is only in Russian.

Comment: Maybe you mean $H(\mathbb{C})$, the ring of entire functions, not the subring of $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ consisting of convergent power series?  The former is not Noetherian, while the latter is Noetherian. This is confusing, because, at first glance, one would think they would be isomorphic rings (send a function to its power series expansion). But I think maybe the multiplication is not preserved?  Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @mbrown The ring of entire functions is isomorphic (canonically, almost) to the ring of everywhere convergent power series.

Comment: @DanielFischer What made me doubt this was the reference Alex Youcis quoted.  I didn't realize the Zariski-Samuel text meant the ring of power series with nonzero radius of convergence, which is Noetherian, but this must be what they are talking about.

Comment: @mbrown I don't have Zariski-Samuel at hand to check what they prove and write. I guess what they prove is a) that the ring of formal power series is Noetherian (a PID even, if I'm not totally off base), and then b) that the "ring of convergent power series", meaning power series having a positive radius of convergence, but without positive lower bound of the convergence radii, which is isomorphic to the ring of germs of holomorphic functions, is also Noetherian, and Alex overlooked "everywhere". Fixing a positive lower bound for the convergence radii changes the picture.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for setting me straight. By the way, the ring of formal power series over any field is indeed a PID.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I did look over this fact. The power series ring over a field is even a DVR by the way :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis In fact, it's even a *complete* DVR. :)

Comment: @Marie An adjective contest, eh?

Comment: @AlexYoucis A *fun* adjective contest!

Answer (score 7):

The ring of everywhere convergent power series is isomorphic to the ring $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ of entire functions. More generally, the ring of power series with radius of convergence at least $R$ is isomorphic to the ring $\mathcal{O}(D_R)$ of holomorphic functions on the disk $D_R = \{ z \in\mathbb{C} : \lvert z\rvert < R\}$. The isomorphisms are given by the Taylor expansion about $0$.

A consequence of the Weierstraß product theorem is that no ring $\mathcal{O}(U)$, where $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a domain, is Noetherian.

Choose any infinite discrete subset $V$ of $U$, and let

$$\mathfrak{I} = \{ f \in \mathcal{O}(U) : f(z) = 0 \text{ for almost all } z \in V\}.$$

This ideal is not finitely generated.

Comment: In fact, the only finitely generated ideals of $\mathcal{O}(U)$ for a domain $U$ are the principal ones!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, in every Noetherian ring, any non-unit, non-zero element is, up to units, a finite product of irreducibles. The irreducibles in $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ are easily seen to be the functions $z-a$. Thus, if $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C})$ was Noetherian, then every non-unit, non-zero element would need to be a polynomial. This is certainly not true :)

Comment: A polynomial times $e^f$ with $f$ entire. That still leaves only finitely many zeros, which means $\sin$ isn't a (finite) product of irreducibles.