# Atiyah Macdonald Exercise 7.4

Tags: complex-analysis, commutative-algebra, power-series, noetherian

Exercise 7.4 in Atiyah-Macdonald asks which of the following rings are Noetherian (numbering to match the book where there are other parts of the problem):

2. The ring of power series in $z$ with a positive radius of convergence.
3. The ring of power series in $z$ with an infinite radius of convergence.

For convenience I will call the ring in 2 $A$, and the ring in 3 $B$.

I am able to follow the reasoning in [these solutions](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ejcarlson/intro_comm_alg(2019).pdf) showing that $A$ is Noetherian, and the solution by Alex Youcis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521658/the-ring-of-convergent-power-series-over-mathbb-c-isnt-noetherian) showing that $B$ is not Noetherian. My question is - **how does the argument showing that $B$ is not Noetherian not apply to $A$ as well**?

If "positive radius" includes infinite radius, then $\sin(z)$ is in $A$, but is a nonzero, non-unit that is not a finite product of irreducibles, so $A$ should not be Notherian. On the other hand, if "positive radius" does not include infinite radius, then where do we use the assumption that our radius of convergence is finite in showing that $A$ is Noetherian?

Comment: It includes infinite radius, but what are the irreducibles in $A$? To give you a sense of what can happen, consider the series $1-z$. In your ring $B$, $1-z$ is a nonzero, nonunit, irreducible element. However, in your ring $A$, $1-z$ is a unit! Indeed, the geometric series, $1+z+z^2+\cdots$ has radius of convergence equal to $1$ and serves as an inverse to $1-z$. Think about what ramifications this has for $\sin(z)$ as an element of $A$.

Comment: It has to include infinite radius, as otherwise it wouldn't be closed under addition, as evidenced by $$(1+z+z^2+\cdots)+(-1-z-z^2-\cdots)$$

Comment: @Arthur - good point, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @metalspringpro - Is the takeaway in this case that in $A$, after factoring out $z$ from the power series for $\sin(z)$, we get that $\sin(z) = z g$, where $g$ has nonzero constant term, and is therefore a unit in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$, and so also in $A$? So $\sin(z)$ is a finite product of irreducibles and units, whereas in $B$ the same argument won't work because the power series for $z / \sin(z)$ centered at $0$ has finite radius of convergence ($\frac{\pi}{2}$ I believe...), so $g$ is not a unit?

Comment: @stillconfused This is correct: $\sin(z)=zg$, where $g$ is a unit in $\mathbb{C}[\![z]\!]$ and where $1/g$ has a finite positive radius of convergence (the radius is $\pi$ in fact). Thus $g$ is a unit in $A$ but is not a unit in $B$.